# Can in_memory act as a regular directory in the memory?

Tags: arcpy, geoprocessing, esri-geodatabase, in-memory

I am having trouble with raster clipping whenever the result is saved to a GDB,
is there any other way to geoprocess in the memory and have the results behave as if saved to a normal directory?

Comment: What do you mean, "normal directory"? Like a folder on disk?  in_memory is a basically an fGDB. If you want to save a raster to in_memory, its like saving it into the that GDB.

Comment: This is an example of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Instead of asking about an unworkable  solution, please document the root problem.

Comment: Can you post your code along with details of what problem you're experiencing with fGDB raster please.

Comment: @KHimba Yes, I mean like a folder on disk. I wish to save a raster to a folder, but have it work fast as in_memory.

Comment: @Vince Sorry for XYing. should I delete this thread and open a new more detailed one?

Comment: @MichaelStimson Sure, should I do it here or replace this thread with a detailed one?

Comment: Just replace this content with a detailed description of the problem.

Comment: Edit your question and include some of your code (as text and format with the {} button) if you have error messages include them too (also as text, but if they are a popup a screen shot Alt+PrtScn trimmed would be better than nothing).